# Why can extension method not overwrite original object?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

It seems that an extension method in C# cannot overwrite the original object. Why is that? Example:

```
using System;

namespace ExtensionTest
{
    public class MyTest {
        public string MyName { get; set; } 
    }


    class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myTest = new MyTest() { MyName = "Arne" };
            Console.WriteLine("My name is {0}", myTest.MyName);
            // Will write "My name is Arne"
            myTest.AlterMyTest();
            Console.WriteLine("My name is {0}", myTest.MyName);
            // Will write "My name is Bertil"
            myTest.OverwriteMyTest();
            Console.WriteLine("My name is {0}", myTest.MyName);
            // Will write "My name is Bertil" (why?)
        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionClass{
        public static void AlterMyTest(this MyTest myTest)
        {
            myTest.MyName = "Bertil";
        }

         public static void OverwriteMyTest(this MyTest myTest)
         {
             myTest = new MyTest() { MyName = "Carl" };
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only do this for `ref` arguments and you cannot have `this` and `ref` at the same time. I do not know _why_, but I have encountered the same situation also.

Comment: The more pressing question is, why would you want to?

Comment: This is because the compiler simply converts the extension method into a static method call, and just hasn't got support for `ref`, probably because the use case for such a feature is limited. Also, this code smells a little.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Its code to demonstrate a strange behaviour, of course it smells

Comment: How is this related to extension methods? Can you provide an example of a method that can do it?

Comment: @PatrikHägne The code is using an extension method to add functionality to the MyTest class

Comment: Again: Can you provide an example of a method that _can_ do this? I can't see that it would be possible in any type of method so it's not related to extension methods per sé.

Comment: @PatrikHägne A non-extension method could use `ref`, an extension method cannot use `ref`, so yes, it is related.

Comment: So the question is really: "Why can't extension methods use ref- or out-parameters?"?

Comment: @PatrikHägne It might be if C# was the only context you had.

Comment: @c0m4 Which I'm sure is the case for everyone but you. Great we got that sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because as usual, reference of the class is copied while passing to the method, and you are assigning new object to the new reference.

For not-extension methods, you can pass reference by `ref/out` keywords

```
public static void Func(out MyClass b)
{
   b = new MyClass();
}

...
MyClass b;
Func(out b);
Assert.IsNotNull(b);
```

but C# compiler doesn't allow to use `ref` with `this`(the reason is in David Arno's comment). You are free to remove `this` keyword, and call static method instead of extension.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference of the Class"? We are not dealing with objects now?

Comment: @c0m4 He means a reference to an object. The line `myTest = new MyTest() ...` simply changes the object that `myTest` references. It's a flaw in the C# language that it allows you to modify parameters, rather than a flaw in extension methods.

Comment: @c0m4, you are dealing with class using it's reference, there are a lot of talking about this in the web, just google reference types and value types in c#

Comment: "but C# compiler doesn't allow to use ref with this, not sure why" - because it would be nonsensical. It would mean that foo.bar() could result in foo referencing a completely different instance of Foo without warning. A nightmare recipe for hard to track bugs.

Comment: ahh, sure @DavidArno :) I said that without deep thinking :) thanks, edited

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: You are mixing `out` and `ref`. Either define it with `ref` and call it with `ref` or define it with `out` and call it with `out`.

Comment: @DavidArno: There are many cases where it would be useful to have methods which modify a variable be bound to the type of variable they're modifying.  While it would probably not be good to use syntax which looks just like an ordinary method call, being able to say something like `someDelegate ref.AddSubscriber(otherDelegate);` (with `AddSubscriber` being threadsafe) would seem cleaner than `DelegateHelper.AddSubscriber(ref someDelegage, otherDelegate);`.